# Reference request: most hyperplane sections contain one node

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb {CP}^n$ be a smooth hypersurface. It is known that most of hyperplane sections are smooth. My question is

> Is it true that most of the singular sections contain one node?

I think it is true and also used it for a long time, but I just realized I never knew how to prove this. Could someone give a reference about it?

I also tried to do computation directly. For hypersurfaces of degree $2$, they are all of the form like $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=0$, so easy to see all the sections are smooth. For higher degree I don't know a good way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean for hypersurface of degree $2$ : for example the intersection of $x_0 = 0$ with $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 0$ gives you a singular quadric.

Comment: It's always possible to find a pencil of hyperplane sections such that the singular sections contain at worst one node. These are called Lefschetz pencils. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Isn't the intersection still smooth? We are considering the homogenous coordinate.

Comment: @Akatsuki : no since there is one less variable, e.g $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$ is not smooth in $\Bbb P^2$ since it's a union of two lines intersecting at a point. In general, quadrics in $\Bbb P^n$ are classified by their rank, and smooth only if the rank is maximal.

Comment: Also I have no ideas for a reference sorry, but maybe the first pages of Lamotke's article about topology of projective varieties contains something ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet But I think in your case the rank is still maximal. When taking intersection with $x_0=0$ we are considering the intersection in the total space $\mathbb P^{n-1}$, i.e. the dimension of total space also decreases.

Comment: @Akatsuki : Of course you are right, sorry about it. But I still think there might be singularity : for example an hyperplane section of a conic curve is not always smooth since it's not always reduced.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yes you are right. Just take the hyperplane $x_0=i x_1$. Sorry for this. I will edit it.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet But it is strange. Isn't it an example all singular sections are non-reduced? Hence the statement in the question is not true?

Comment: @Akatsuki : I think that's ok, because 0-dimensional nodes are non-reduced points given by $x^2 = 0$ in affine chart. I'm sure that your statement is true but I don't know a reference where this is proved.

Comment: @Akatsuki : sorry to bother you again, I think I have a cleaner argument than before, I hope that will be useful.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I am very sorry for reply so late. (my computer was broken so I did not have regular access to Internet until it is fixed now) Yes, it is very good argument. Btw, I also found similar things at SGA 7 II, Exp. XVII, Prop. 3.2.

Comment: @Akatsuki : no worries ! I'm glad it was useful, I also heard that SGA 7 was also a good reference for Lefschetz pencils, maybe it's time to take a look ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Proposition** : Let $\hat{X}$ be the dual variety. Let $T \subset \hat{\Bbb P^n}$ be a line such that $T$ avoids the singular locus of $\hat{X}$ and is transverse to $\hat{X}$ : then $H_t \cap X$ is a Lefschetz pencil.

Clearly, this implies that if $t$ is not in the singular locus of $\hat{X}$ then $H_t \cap X$ has a nodal singularity. Since the singular hyperplanes sections are parametrized by $\hat{X}$ (also proved in Lamotke) you obtain that a generic singular hyperplane section has nodal singularities.

For a proof of the proposition, see "The topology of projective algebraic varieties after S.Lefschetz" by K. Lamotke, paragraph 1.6, in particular 1.6.4.

Comment: I think the condition "transversal intersection with $\hat X$" may not be necessary: in the definition of Lefschetz pencil, we only require that the _fiber_ has at most one node, so the proposition should also only have condition on _points_ of $T$. For example, if some $T$ is tangent to $\hat X$ at some point $x$, then we can take another $T'$ transversal to $\hat X$, hence $x$ should also correspond to hypersurface with one node. I don't know if I missed something?